# Display camera output using webforms asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Am developing webform application which scans for QR/barcode for specific duration and perform results based on information read. Am using AForge.net and ZXing.net to access camera. The camera lights up and keeps sending BMP frames to ZXing library to detect QR code. Everything works fine and QR code gets detected.

The requirement is also to display a video stream of what is read from camera so that the user can place QR code at right position. On winforms, there are tons of assistance on how this is possible but couldn't find a good direction for webforms. Google search mostly results in windows forms and **not** **webforms**.

Any help is really appreciated. I know i can't use deprecated javascript handlers (flash player) which are not handled in android/iOS (correct me if I am wrong).

Have attached a snippet of code which was provided by AForge.net on reading QR code. All I need is to create a player and pass the bmp frames. Any suggestions to documents or sample code is highly appreciated.

Code snippet:

```
    protected void video_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        // get new frame
        Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;

        // process the frame
        var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader();

        // decode the barcode from the in memory bitmap
        var barcodeResult = barcodeReader.Decode(bitmap);

        if (barcodeResult != null && barcodeResult.Text.Length != 0)
        {
            // signal to stop when you no longer need capturing
            videoSource.SignalToStop();
            Response.Redirect("Home.aspx?Id=" + barcodeResult.Text, false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Most probably you need client side (javascript) solution. See for example https://a.kabachnik.info/reading-barcodes-with-built-in-camera-with-html5.html

Comment: @AlexKudryashev  - looks like I have to use html and javascript to be called from aspx and ZXing.net library already supports. No need to do any server side stuffs. After striping all of unnecessary controls, am able to achieve the end result. Thanks for redirecting. :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like I have to use html and javascript to be called from aspx and ZXing.net library already supports. No need to do any server side stuffs. After striping all of unnecessary controls, am able to achieve the end result. Thanks for redirecting. :)

https://github.com/zxing-js/library/blob/master/docs/examples/qr-camera/index.html